# Visual Studio 2019 - DataSet tableadapters add ";1" after each stored procedure name

Tags: visual-studio, stored-procedures, visual-studio-2019, tableadapter

So I have to update an old .Net application for my job.
When I open the application's DataSet and want to update one of the tableadapters, I end up with this type of "bug" :

- [the problem in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OkrVM.png)
- [leading to this other problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/soDDG.png)

How CommandText is :

- [with semicolon 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4MDl.png)

How it should be :

- [normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgVaI.png)

I have found a page about this topic but it doesn't help me much, because I can't reinstall the SQL Server in my situation :

https://answers.sap.com/questions/5936797/what%27s-with-the-semicolon-1-notation-in-stored-pro.html

Do you have any idea how to resolve this problem ?

Edit:

- Application is VB.Net Framework 4.5.2
- SQL Server 2016 with a database compatible with SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer !

- Problem : The ConnectionString was using **System.Data.Odbc**

  ```
  <add name="myApp.My.MySettings.myConnectionString" connectionString="Dsn=myDataBase;app=myAppProd;database=myDataBase;trusted_connection=Yes" providerName="System.Data.Odbc" />
  ```
- Solution : I switched to **System.Data.SqlClient**

  ```
  <add name="myApp.My.MySettings.myConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=mySQLServer;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  ```

Everything works as excepted !
Hope it helps others encountering this same problem

Edit: Had to make another DataSet because it keeps auto-generating code with Odbc component even after updating the ConnectionString...